# client side javascript code in Adobe Livecycle Designer to grow the number of rows in table by entering a number in number field

Tags: adobe

plz anyone provide me with the client side JavaScript code in Adobe Livecycle Designer to grow the number of rows in table on entering a number in number field.

Comment: Stack Overflow expect that you put some effort in your question, no just asking for code to solve your problem. Do some research and come back with a more precise question.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript something like:

```
for (var i=0; i<NumberFieldName.rawValue; i++) {
   TableName._RowName.addInstance(0);
}
```